# ESLint throwing unpredicted errors with Hardhat

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, hardhat

I recently began a project which uses hardhat. I ran `npx hardhat .`, and went with the advanced TS project.

Everything works fine, from the types to the solidity compiling, but ESLint always complains...

This is the kind of error I keep seeing:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the types are there, but ESLint continues to throw errors. This luckily doesn't stop the app to run.

Here is my config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: false,
    es2021: true,
    mocha: true,
    node: true
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  extends: ['standard', 'plugin:node/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12
  },
  rules: {
    'node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax': [
      'error',
      { ignores: ['modules'] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: which IDE is this? some of the IDEs stop complaining after a good restart

Comment: It's VSCode. Thought for a second you were right, but then the errors came flooding in! I've even completely removed the eslint config but the errors still remain. I really can't come to a conclusion about these errors.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of time on this issue, and the best method for me was to remove everything.

1 - Create a `.ptettierrc.json` file the root of your project.

2 - Run `yarn remove eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-node eslint-plugin-import eslint-config-standard eslint-config-prettier`

3 - Change your ESLint config to the one below:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: false,
    es2021: true,
    mocha: true,
    node: true
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  extends: ['plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12
  },
  rules: {
    'node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax': [
      'error',
      { ignores: ['modules'] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Keep in mind this is for a fresh config, if you've already changed your config, just remove any mentions of the package we removed on step 2.

Comment: Adding to this, the root cause seems to be `'plugin:node/recommended'`, so removing this seems to resolve the issue (although you may lose other linting benefits included with node/recommended)